# Creating virtual hosts for using same domain based on directories

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I want to have a new version of an application which requires a fresh install to be in a new sub dir.
Example the old version is at a location `var\www\html`.
The new version I need to have at `var\www\5.0`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<VirtualHost>
```

This works for `www.example.com`
I created another virtual host file enabled it using `a2ensite` for `www.example.com/5.0`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.example.com/5.0
    ServerAlias www.example.com/5.0
    DocumentRoot /var/www/5.0
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<VirtualHost>
```

but this does not work. I don't want the new version to be inside the existing html folder.
Also, I do not want to create new subdomain for new version as I want it to use both versions in parallel.

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`ServerName`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) is not an URL. It can only be a hostname.

You seem to be looking for the [**`Alias`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) Directive instead, to map an URL to a file-system location:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Alias /5.0   /var/www/5.0
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Will this open `/html` when I hit `www.example.com` ? and `/5.0` when I hit `www.example.com/5.0`. I need both to be working independently for the respective  URLs. Both have entirely different versions installed.

Comment: INdeed. Content for www.example.com will come from the DocumentRoot, from `/var/www/html` **except** requests starting with `/5.0`, those will be mapped to the Alias target directory  `/var/www/5.0` .

Comment: Yes that worked SIR. Thank you for the guidance. @HBrujin